# Writing the total request time in seconds to an nginx access log, possibly using a calculated variable

Tags: nginx

I'm trying to modify my nginx access log format to include the request duration, in seconds.

I see two possible variables I could use:

1) [`$request_time`](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpLogModule#log_format)

2) [`$upstream_response_time`](http://wiki.nginx.org/NginxHttpUpstreamModule#.24upstream_response_time)

However both of these variables are expressed in microseconds, and I need this value to be rendered in seconds. Is there any way to specify the output as an expression (i.e. `$request_time * 1000`) or accomplish this in some other way?

Thanks

Comment: Actually, both are already in seconds (with millisecond resolution, i.e. `$request_time` will look like `1.234`). Note well that `$upstream_response_time` format is more complex as it might contain timing for [multiple upstream servers](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_upstream_module.html#variables).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The webserver is not a calculator or statistical program. It's logging function is to provide the raw data you can do your analysis with. If you analysis program is incapable of converting microseconds to seconds you should shop around for other software. In any case, it us unrealistic to expect a program's logging function to perform unit conversions for you. The goal of logging is not to format, yet to record what it has done without impacting the performance of it's core functionality.

Answer (score 1):

If you use a reporter like LogStash (ELK stack) you can do some calculation when parsing the log. Here is my example to convert second into millisecond in my Logstash filter for Nginx:

```
grok {
      match => {
        "message" => "%{IPORHOST:clientip} %{USER:ident} %{USER:auth} \[%{HTTPDATE:timestamp}\] \"%{WORD:verb} %{URIPATHPARAM:logMessage} HTTP/%{NUMBER:httpversion}\" %{NUMBER:response} (?:%{NUMBER:bytes}|-) (?:\"(?:%{URI:referrer}|-)\"|%{QS:referrer}) %{QS:agent} rt=%{NUMBER:duration_sec} cid=%{GREEDYDATA:correlationId}"
      }
}
mutate { convert => [ "duration_sec", "float" ] }
ruby { code => "event['duration_ms'] = event['duration_sec'].to_f * 1000" }
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

As noted in the comments `$request_time` is already in seconds, however it is possible to convert to another unit purely in nginx config as follows.

I realise this is an old question but it seems to get a lot of traffic so perhaps the below will help someone else who, like me, might want to convert to a different unit, in my case nanoseconds (though if you want milliseconds then simply omit the 6 trailing zeros).

This is useful for sending to the Elastic `event.duration` field - to avoid the faff of an ingest pipeline or similar on the Elastic end (to multiply by 1000000) you can instead do some hideous regex as below.

The fact that `$request_time` is always zero-padded to 3 decimal places helps, so in the common cases you can append 6 zeros - but you also have to handle leading zeros (before & after the decimal point) to make sure the result doesn't end up with any leading zeros:

```
map $request_time $request_time_nanos {
    # Simple case for 0.000
    ~^0\.000$ 0;
    # If 0 before decimal place, must remove leading zeros after it, before adding 6 zeros
    ~^0\.(?:0*)([^0].*)$ $1000000;
    # Otherwise just concatenate the full pre- & post-decimal parts, before adding 6 zeros
    ~^([^0][^.]*)\.(.*)$ $1$2000000;
}
```

Example transformations (commas inserted for readability only):

```
[sec]    [nanoseconds]
0.000 =>             0
0.110 =>   110,000,000
0.010 =>    10,000,000
1.010 => 1,010,000,000
```